# How to set the data type as a model in strong loop remote method definition

Tags: node.js, strongloop

I whant to set the data type of my remote method as a model. If I'm in User.js I can do this:

```
User.remoteMethod('contacts',  {
    accepts: [
        {
            arg: 'contacts', 
            type: User, 
        }
    ],
    returns: {arg: 'data', type: 'json'}
});
```

but I have another model named Contac and I want to replace "type: User" with "type: Contact".
But on this context, I think that the app object can't be access so if there is any way to do this?

Comment: are you trying to perform operations on Contac object in User.js?

Comment: no, just have access to Contac model in User.js, so I could set the type: Contact

Comment: I tried to recreate your problem and faced no problem as long as it's an proper object. Though I'll post the answer regarding accessing app object.

Answer (score 0):

To access `app` object in `model.js`,

```
ModelName.getApp(function(err, app) {
    if(err) throw err;

    //use app object here. for eg.
    //app.models.Contact.find({}, function(err, contacts) {
    //    if(err) throw err;
    //    console.log(contacts);
    //});
});
```

This way you can get `app` object and use it to access other models.

Answer (score 0):

I think the type that you want is 'object' which can be everything as a object.
It depends on your really input. If you want POST the whole user or contact as a json data, 'object' is recommended, or if you just want input a foreignKey like "contactId" to indicate a contact, an id is adequate because you can get the instance in your logic code of the remote method like:

```
User.contact = function (contactId, cb){
  Contact = User.app.models.Contact // suppose Contact is the so-called another model
  Contact.findById(contactId,function(err,instance){
    ...
  cb(null, JSON.stringify(instance); //instance is the contact whose id is contactId
  });
}
```